# Candlestick chart on pyvista

Tags: python, python-3.x, candlestick-chart, pyvista

I've spent the day trying to familiarize myself with pyvista through example text and I have a long way to go but there's a specific thing I want to do with pyvista that I can't seem to figure out.

I want to make a candlestick chart for stocks and stuff and I want to use pyvista because it supposedly handles lots of visual data points smoothly but I can't figure out how to make a 2D bar whos top and bottom can be placed on an arbitrary position on a chart grid.

[image]

The built in chart functions don't seem to support detaching bars from the 0 point and I'm having issues making a 2d bar in the 3d options without divide by zero errors or random grids being placed on the bar.
I'm also having trouble putting a scale on the 3d options.

[image]

Can someone be kind enough to point me in the right direction?
Would be much appreciated since pyvista is a beast and I need some sort of direction.
I've tried using the .bar method for 2D

```
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

x = [2]
y = [5]

chart = pv.Chart2D()
chart.bar(x, y)
chart.x_axis.tick_locations = x

chart.grid = False  # Disable the grid lines

chart.show()
```

I've tried using the structures grid method here

```
import pyvista
import vtk
import numpy as np
from numpy import mgrid
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


vtkgrid = vtk.vtkStructuredGrid()
grid = pyvista.StructuredGrid(vtkgrid)

xrng = np.arange(-10, 10, 1, dtype=np.float32)
yrng = np.arange(-10, 10, 1, dtype=np.float32)
zrng = np.arange(-1, 0, 1, dtype=np.float32)
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(xrng, yrng, zrng)
grid = pyvista.StructuredGrid(x, y, z)

p = pyvista.Plotter(notebook=0, shape=(1,1))
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap("viridis", 4)
p.background_color='white'

p.add_mesh(grid, cmap=cmap)

print(xrng)

# grid = pv.StructuredGrid(x, y, z)
p.show_grid()
# grid.plot()
p.show()
```

I've tried editing this hexahedron script and managed to get flat squares but adding a grid scale to attach it to for coordinates is a whole nothing story

```
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv
import numpy as np
import vtk
import pyvista as pv


offset = np.array([0, 9])
cells = np.array([8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
cell_type = np.array([vtk.VTK_HEXAHEDRON, vtk.VTK_HEXAHEDRON])
cell1 = np.array(
    [
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1],
    ]
)

cell2 = np.array(
    [
        [0, 2, 3],
        [0, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 3],
        [0, 1, 3],
        [0, 2, 4],
        [0, 2, 4],
        [0, 1, 4],
        [0, 1, 4],
    ]
)

points = np.vstack((cell1, cell2))
grid = pv.UnstructuredGrid(offset, cells, cell_type, points)
cells_hex = np.arange(16).reshape([2, 8])
grid = pv.UnstructuredGrid({vtk.VTK_HEXAHEDRON: cells_hex}, points)

_ = grid.plot(show_edges=True)
```

My main issue is constructing a grid for the bar coordinates to be attached to and allowing the bar to placed arbitrarily upon the grid.

Comment: Pyvista is an awesome library, I used it a lot for 3D stuff! However, for this kind of problems I think that maybe `bokeh` is an easier option. Take a look [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/candlestick.html). (That's just an opinion of mine).

Comment: Unfortunately I have many plans for  2D and 3D rending of millions of data points.
I don't want to shy away from the opportunity to learn pyvista, even if it is more difficult. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: It makes sense! Can you please provide the code you have written so far? Thanks! Your question could get downvoted if you do not show what you have actually tried so far.